# How can i show Windows processes in for example textEdit in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt

I want to ask you how can i show Windows processes in (for example)textEdit in Qt Creator? is it possible? Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a snapshot which lets you enumerate all process of the system using the functions mentioned in [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). After that, it's just a matter of putting all the information into a Qt control.

Comment: Yes i also find something like that but i don´t know how to put it in to qt creator. Is somewhere some guide or something how to put c++ code (like in example) to qt creator?